# Riemann hypothesis for the motivic zeta function

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

To repair the failure of rationality in general (as shown by Larsen and Lunts for products of two curves of genus > 1) of M. Kapranov's zeta function defined for a variety over a field $k$ and valued in the power series ring over the Grothendieck ring of varieties over $k$, Y. André instead defines the following motivic zeta function for a pure motive $M$ over $k$:
$$ Z_{mot} (M, t) = 1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty [Sym^nM] t^n \in K_0(Mot_k)[[t]]$$
where $K_0(Mot_k)$ is the $K$-ring of pure motives over $k$.

He shows that $ Z_{mot} (M, t)$ is a rational function of $t$ for any finite-dimensional motive with rational coefficients. B. Kahn has established a functional equation for $ Z_{mot} (M, t)$ relating it to $ Z_{mot} (M^\vee, t)$.

There is no mention of a Riemann hypothesis anywhere, however, that I have been able to find. In analogy with the Weil conjectures and by the requirement of compatibility with them under the point-counting homomorphism when $k$ is a finite field, the motivic Riemann hypothesis should take the form: if $\alpha \in K_0(Mot_k)$ is a root of a polynomial appearing in the numerator or denominator of the rational function $ Z_{mot} (M, t)$, then $\alpha \otimes \alpha^\vee = \mathbb{L}^i$, for an appropriate power $i$ of the class of the affine line.

Is there an obvious reason why it or something similar would not hold true and which is why it is not discussed?